# Lighttpd proxy, and letsencrypt renewal

Tags: lets-encrypt, lighttpd

I need some help on this subject.
I have many domains in the same lighttpd config, and I will move to letsencrypt cert, so I'm simulating on a dummy server.

I have the following:

```
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*$" {

        $HTTP["host"] == "autosslxlm3.ddns.net" {

                $SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
                        ssl.engine = "enable"
                        ssl.ca-file = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/autosslxlm3.ddns.net/chain.pem"
                        ssl.pemfile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/autosslxlm3.ddns.net/web.pem"
                }
                proxy.balance = "round-robin"
                proxy.server = ("" => (
                        ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 8888 ))
                )
        }
}
```

If I access in https, I get the following error in lighttpd error.log:

> no certificate/private key for TLS server name autosslxlm3.ddns.net

Which is not true, as it is there, and if I remove the line

```
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*$" {
```

(and of course the closing bracket at the bottom), it works perfectly in https!
But that will not make possible to renew the cert, as the /.well-known/... will be forwarded to what's running on port 8888, while it should go to some folder on system.

With the full config, if I also change anything in the pem file location for example, lighttpd will not start, so, it is reading the configuration correctly, but with that first line certificate is considered "invalid" or not present.

lighttpd/1.4.53

Thanks in advance

Comment: While I haven't used lighttpd in a long time, I think the problem makes sense considering that `$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*$"` relies on the HTTP request path. Things then become rather backwards when the TLS/SSL configuration (required to establish the connection *before* the request can happen) is dependent on that path. Can you just reorder the conditions somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the socket at the top level, not nested in the other conditions.

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" { ... }
```

TLS and certificate selection occur **before** the HTTP request URL is known, so that `$HTTP["url"]` condition can not evaluate to true until **after** the TLS connection is set up.